# C# Loop to scan top,bottom,left,right elements of 2d Array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, uwp-xaml

I am trying to complete a game over condition for a peg solitaire game i am writing.

I have all of the movements and pieces removing as they should.
Each piece is held within a 2d array as an Ellipse UI Ellement and when a piece is taken it is replaced with a border Ui Element.

I have started to use a method adapted from a [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471463/find-adjacent-elements-in-a-2d-matrix) that scans the 8 adjacent squares around the array element.

```
   public static IEnumerable<T> AdjacentElements<T>(T[,] arr, int row, int column)
    {
        int rows = arr.GetLength(0);
        int columns = arr.GetLength(1);

        for (int j = row - 1; j <= row + 1; j++)
            for (int i = column - 1; i <= column + 1; i++)
                if (i >= 0 && j >= 0 && i < columns && j < rows && !(j == row && i == column))
                    yield return arr[j, i];
    }
}
```

The method called once a piece is taken.

```
 var results = AdjacentElements(grid, 3, 3);
        foreach (var result in results)

            Debug.WriteLine(result);
```

When it encounters an ellipse it should check the squares directly above,below,left and right of the Ellipse, at the moment is all 8 squares, i only need four (top, bottom, left and right).

I am using grid reference 3,3 to test at the moment and it is printing out as expected but for all 8 squares.

If any of the four squares in turn encounter and ellipse the next square in a straight line should be a Border in order to be a possible move.

For example:

Circle 1 is the Ellipse being checked.
The circles below,left and right are ignored.
The Cirle 2 is chosen as Square 3 is empty.
This would produce a valid move so the game would continue.
If no valid move is found the game will end.

I not sure how to proceed with this, I was thinking of putting the method call inside a nested for loop to go over every element but I'm thinking it would be very inefficient.

```
 var results = AdjacentElements(grid, i, j);
    foreach (var result in results)

        //condition here
```

[image]

Comment: What is your actual problem, why not just look around the array x,y what are you actually stuck on

Comment: To loop each element in  the array needs a nested for loop. Then within each element if an ellipse is found i need to go out another level to check for another ellipse. Then out one more in the same direction to check for and ellipse again.

Comment: Does this need a lot of nested loops or is here another way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think i truly understand what you want to do. However, yes you could do nested loops. but sometimes its just easier to poke at it

**Given some array x, y**

```
var x = 23;
var y = 3;
```

**Exmaple**

```
var checks = List<Point>();

checks.Add(new Point(x+1,y));
checks.Add(new Point(x-1,y));
checks.Add(new Point(x,y+1));
checks.Add(new Point(x,y-1));

foreach(var check in checks)
   //If Bounds check
   //do what you need to do
```